# Convert Google ProtocolBuffer.ProtocolMessage to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers

I am attempting to convert a google.net.proto.ProtocolBuffer.ProtocolMessage (which is protobuf v1) [implemented in this class](https://github.com/AppScale/gae_sdk/blob/master/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_pb.py) to a JSON string.  I have tried several utilities that claim to be able to convert protocol buffers, but all of them appear to be exclusive to protobuf v2.

Does anyone have insight into how a v1 protobuf object could be converted to JSON?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protobufs v1 as never officially released publicly, but leaked out as part of the App Engine SDK. As such, you're unlikely to find any tools built around it. Moreover, the v1 API never really supported things like converting to JSON -- the concept of reflection was a major improvement introduced by v2. In the v1 days, any "generic" algorithms (e.g. converting a protobuf to text) had to inspect the serialized bytes rather than the parsed object.

That said, one simple thing you can do is serialize the v1 protobuf object and then parse it into a v2 object. The wire formats are the same. From there, you can use all the usual v2 tools to do whatever you want with the data.

However, in order to generate a v2 object, you of course need the original `.proto` file. I couldn't find this file in the repository to which you linked, although I only looked briefly. It's possible that the original `.proto` file was not released publicly, in which case your only option would be to reverse-engineer it by looking at the generated source code, which is tedious.